# How can I fill a 2D array spirally in C? Example/problem

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

so I've been struggling with this example for a good hour now and I can't even begin to process how should I do this.

> Write a program that, for given n and m, forms a matrix as described.
> The matrix should be m x m, and it's filled "spirally" with it's
> beginning in the upper left corner. The first value in the matrix is
> the number n. It's repeated until the "edge" of the matrix, at which
> point the number increments. After the number 9 goes 0. 0 ≤ n ≤ 9, 0 ≤
> m ≤ 9

[image: Example for n=3, m=5]

Comment: Can you work out how to do it on paper first?

Comment: Naïve approach: I'd start with `x=0`, `y=0`, `dx=1` and `dy=0` value used to navigate. Keep populating with `n` until you reach the limit of `y`, then increment and "rotate" your `dx`/`dy` pair. It'd help to have the thing filled with `-1` first so you can detect previously populated cells as well as edges.

Comment: I tried working it out by commenting in CodeBlocks, and tried to find a pattern in how the row/column numbers change values

Comment: Smarter approach: Work it out linearly, then "pack" it into a spiral when displaying it. There's a pattern to which locations to display. In a linear sequence you see: `n-1` x `(n)`, `m-1` x `(n+1) % 10`, etc.

Comment: The naive approach was the first idea that crossed my mind, exactly that, to the letter. But I get confused when I try to implement it lol

Comment: I'll go try the smarter approach

Comment: This is one of those things that helps to work out on paper first to look for patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Some time ago I had made a function to display the numbers 1 to n on an odd-sized grid.
The principle was to start from the center and to shift by ;*

- x = 1
- x box on the right
- x box on the bottom
- x++
- x box on the left
- x box at the top
- x++

*With this simple algorithm, you can easily imagine to maybe start from the center of your problem and decrement your value, it seems easier to start from the center.*

---

Here is the code that illustrates the above solution, to be adapted of course for your problem, it's only a lead.

```
#define WE 5

void    clock(int grid[WE][WE])
{
    int count;
    int i;
    int reach;
    int flag;
    int tab[2] = {WE / 2, WE / 2}; //x , y

    count = 0;
    flag = 0;
    i = 0;
    reach = 1;
    grid[tab[1]][tab[0]] = count;
    for (int j = 0; j < WE - 1 && grid[0][WE - 1] != pow(WE, 2) - 1; j++)
        for (i = 0; i < reach && grid[0][WE - 1] != pow(WE, 2) - 1; i++, reach++)
        {
            if(flag % 2 == 0)
            {
                for(int right = 0 ; right < reach ; right++, tab[0]++, count++, flag = 1)
                    grid[tab[1]][tab[0]] = count;
                if(reach < WE - 1)
                    for(int bottom = 0; bottom < reach; bottom++, count++, tab[1]++)
                        grid[tab[1]][tab[0]] = count;
            }
            else
            {
                for(int left = 0; left < reach; left++, count++, tab[0]--, flag = 0)
                    grid[tab[1]][tab[0]] = count;
                for(int top = 0; top < reach; top++, tab[1]--, count++)
                    grid[tab[1]][tab[0]] = count;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll make sure to try that since I do have another similar problem. I already solved this one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. If anybody's interested, here's how I did it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//Fills the row number "row" with the number n
int fillRow(int m, int n, int arr[m][m], int row)
{
    int j;

    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
    {
        if(arr[row][j] == -1 || arr[row][j] == n-1) arr[row][j] = n;
    }

}

//Fills the column number "col" with the number n
int fillCol(int m, int n, int arr[m][m], int col)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i][col] == -1 || arr[i][col] == n-1) arr[i][col] = n;
    }

}

int main()
{

    int n, m, i, j, r=1, c=1, row=-1, col=-1;

    scanf("%d %d",&n, &m);

    int arr[m][m];
    
    
    //Fill array with -1 everywhere
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = -1;
        }

    }
    
    //Calculate which row/column to fill (variables row/col)
    //Fill row then column then row than column...
    for(i=0;i<2*m;i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0)
        {
            row = (r%2==0) ? m-r/2 : r/2;
            fillRow(m, n, arr, row);
            n++;
            r++;
        }
        else if(i%2==1)
        {
            col = (c%2==0) ? c/2-1 : m-c/2-1;
            fillCol(m, n, arr, col);
            n++;
            c++;
        }
    }
    
    //If an element is larger than 9, decrease it by 10
    //Prints the elements
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            if(arr[i][j]>9) arr[i][j] -=10;
            printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```